# Detect virtual keyboard when focusing on a TextBox inside a userControl

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a the Following FlipView in a winRT project

```
<FlipView x:Name="Flip" GotFocus="FlipView_GotFocus" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Controls, ElementName=pageRoot}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedControl, ElementName=pageRoot, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
```

inside of it i will have several usercontrols that have some TextBox, but when i focus in one of the TextBox , the virtual Keyboard gets in front of the other TextBox, it doesnt "lift" the app like it normally does when i have a simple page with TextBoxs.

Is there a way to detect Keyboard showing up and pulling the view of the app up?

Here is one of the UserControl im using

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <common:ByteArrayToBitmapImageConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToBitmapImageConverter" />
        <common:StringToValidityConverter x:Key="StringToValidityConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource SubHeaderStyle}">
        <Image Source="/Images/Contract/Sales.png" Style="{StaticResource SubHeaderImageStyle}" />
        <TextBlock x:Uid="Sale" Style="{StaticResource SubHeaderTextStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.RowSpan="6" Width="300" Source="{Binding Picture, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToBitmapImageConverter}}" />

        <TextBlock x:Uid="SalesOffice" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Office, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                 common:TextBoxBehavior.Validity="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToValidityConverter}}" />

        <TextBlock x:Uid="SalesAgent" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding AgentName, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                 common:TextBoxBehavior.Validity="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToValidityConverter}}" />

        <TextBlock x:Uid="MobilePhone" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding MobilePhone, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                 common:TextBoxBehavior.Validity="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToValidityConverter}}" InputScope="Number" />

        <TextBlock x:Uid="EmailAddress" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding EmailAddress, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                 common:TextBoxBehavior.Validity="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToValidityConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

and here is how it looks
[image: App when Keyboard is up]

Edit:
seems that i can detect the keyboard with

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Hidding
```

now i just need to learn how to pull my view up.

Comment: This post helped
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/7349d01d-dc0e-4e1c-9327-df90e00fbebf/how-to-handle-the-appearance-of-the-onscreen-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

As you found, you can use the InputPane's Showing and Hiding events to detect the InputPane's visibility changes. The InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs includes the OccludedRect that it will cover, and you can apply a RenderTransform to your page to Translate it out of the way.

```
<Page.RenderTransform>
    <CompositeTransform x:Name="pageTransform"/>
</Page.RenderTransform>
```

And a painfully naive implementation:

```
void Page_Showing(InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs args)
{
    // We probably want something more sophisticated to make sure the
    // focus control and any dependencies are in view
    pageTransform.TranslateY -= args.OccludedRect.Height;
    // Tell the InputPane we already handled things so it doesn't move the page again
    args.EnsuredFocusedElementInView = true;
}

void Page_Hiding(InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs args)
{
    pageTransform.TranslateY = 0;
    args.EnsuredFocusedElementInView = true;
}
```

In reality you'll want to do the math to make sure the necessary controls are in view. You can use animations to make the shift more smooth. If you want to get even more creative you can switch to a new visual state which has just the necessary fields for editing in a more friendly layout. In your UserControl case you may want to shift just the control rather than the page.

Also give it a test on a Windows 10 desktop since the soft-keyboard behavior will interact a bit differently with a windowed app.